# vbUseCompareOption missing from Enum members of vbCompareMethod

Tags: ms-access, vba, string-comparison, collation

Many online, including Microsoft's, help resources (for [example](http://www.trigeminal.com/usenet/usenet001.asp?1033)) for functions that accept a `vbCompareMethod` state that there are 4 possible values:

- `vbUseCompareOption = -1` 'Doesn't seem to exist
- `vbBinaryCompare` = 0
- `vbTextCompare = 1`
- `vbDatabaseCompare = 2`

But I've just checked Access 2000, 2007 and 2016, and none of them seem to list `vbUseCompareOption` in the Object Browser as being present. If I have `Option Explicit` set, I get a compile error saying that `vbUseCompareOption` is an undefined variable.

Does that mean that any VBA that uses the constant `vbUseCompareOption`, without `Option Explicit`, is potentially getting unexpected results?

Is this a throwback to an earlier version of VBA, or perhaps an Access peculiarity, or just a widely distributed error in the help?

Comment: Here's a bunch of Microsoft [pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=vbusecompareoption+site%3Amicrosoft.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab) that refer to the constant.

Comment: The authors of this book make the same observation -  https://books.google.com/books?id=46toCUvklIQC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=vbUseCompareOption&source=bl&ots=joIU1tFAO5&sig=HwI37GfH1v1Y88jEACFtsjz_JHI&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGt-K-h7LcAhUP7J8KHU4jD6UQ6AEIfTAJ#v=onepage&q=vbUseCompareOption&f=false

Comment: Ken Getz was a great VBA author. That book is still the best VBA book, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are right, in that `vbUseCompareOption` does not exisit as a member of enumeration `vbCompareMethod`

[image: vbComapreMethod]

So, what happens when you try and use it?  As you found, when using `Option Explicit` you get a compile error, because a variable of that name *is not defined*.

If you don't use `Option Explicit` (usually a bad idea), a variable is created at run time, of type `Variant`, and value `Empty`.  I ran an experiment to see what happens:

**TL:DR** - yes, you may get unexpected results (Binary Compare is always used)

I created two modules, one with `Option Compare Binary` the other with `Option Compare text`.  I used `StrComp` as a test function that uses a Compare parameter.

**Module one**

```
'Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub DemoText()
    Dim a As String, b As String
    a = "AAA"
    b = "aaa"
    Debug.Print "Option Comapre Text"
    Debug.Print "Text", "Binary", "Omitted", "vbUseCompareOption"
    Debug.Print StrComp(a, b, vbTextCompare), StrComp(a, b, vbBinaryCompare), StrComp(a, b), StrComp(a, b, vbUseCompareOption)
End Sub
```

**Module two**

```
'Option Explicit
Option Compare Binary

Sub DemoBinary()
    Dim a As String, b As String
    a = "AAA"
    b = "aaa"
    Debug.Print "Option Comapre Binary"
    Debug.Print "Text", "Binary", "Omitted", "vbUseCompareOption"
    Debug.Print StrComp(a, b, vbTextCompare), StrComp(a, b, vbBinaryCompare), StrComp(a, b), StrComp(a, b, vbUseCompareOption)
End Sub
```

**The test**

```
Sub Demo()
    DemoText
    DemoBinary
End Sub
```

**The Result**

```
Option Comapre Text
Text          Binary        Omitted       vbUseCompareOption
 0            -1             0            -1 
Option Comapre Binary
Text          Binary        Omitted       vbUseCompareOption
 0            -1            -1            -1
```

And if you assign a value of `-1` to it, you get a run time error 5 "Invalid Procedure Call or argument"

So,  `vbUseCompareOption` does not exist, creating it with a value of `-1` (or just calling a function with `Compare:=-1`) as the help suggests, fails.

Letting VBA create it as a variable (with value `Empty`) has no effect.  Binary compare is always applied.

AFAICT, the only way to use the `Option Compare` setting is to *leave out the Compare parameter* in a function call.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a very good question. I addressed it at the Access team.

That enum member seems to be a left-over from who-knows-where, has never been implemented, and will probably now be removed from the documentation - with some not so high priority.

So, to conclude, all mentions of `vbUseCompareOption` should simply be ignored.

Comment: Interesting. Any idea how they resolved the Bulgarian Locale bug that is mentioned in the "example" link that I included in the original question? Where VbCompareDatabase = 2, and Bulgarian Locale = 2?

Comment: Nonetheless, might be worth me adding as an edge-case, legacy bug inspection in Rubberduck VBA.

Comment: Yep. Also, your original link is for a page of _Michael Kaplan_, it is not official documentation. I've never heard of using LCID this way (it might have been an abandoned unsupported and not fully tested option) and, as MK concludes, one should refrain from experimenting with this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on **chris neilsen**'s post: If no **Option Compare** statement is specified:

**Module Three**

```
'Option Explicit

Sub DemoNoOptionCompare()
    Dim a As String, b As String
    a = "AAA"
    b = "aaa"
    Debug.Print "No 'Option Compare'"
    Debug.Print "Text", "Binary", "Omitted", "vbUseCompareOption"
    Debug.Print StrComp(a, b, vbTextCompare), StrComp(a, b, vbBinaryCompare), StrComp(a, b), StrComp(a, b, vbUseCompareOption)
End Sub

Sub Demo2()
    DemoText
    DemoBinary
    DemoNoOptionCompare
End Sub
```

**The Result**

```
Option Compare Text
Text          Binary        Omitted       vbUseCompareOption
 0            -1             0            -1 
Option Compare Binary
Text          Binary        Omitted       vbUseCompareOption
 0            -1            -1            -1 
No 'Option Compare'
Text          Binary        Omitted       vbUseCompareOption
 0            -1            -1            -1
```

So the default when omitting the ***compare*** argument is controlled by the **Option Compare** statement if it exists, otherwise the default is a binary comparison.